# Return mySQL results for variable number of 'LIKE'

Tags: php, mysql

I know I can use this to check if a column contains either of two values.

`select * from table where field like 'something' or field like 'somethingelse'`

However, in my situation, I have an variable number of `LIKE` to test. There are basically two steps in my code...get the report IDs that the user can access (the variable number) and then get the details for each of these reports.

I'm not sure how to make a single query to do this though (assuming this can be done).

Comment: Did you try `in` query like: `select * from table where id in (1,2,3)` where 1 2 3 are the ids of the reports

Comment: look at the sub queries  too, for example get the IDs and supply that IDs to another query. See the suggestion by @webmaster and put your query which give you the IDs, e.g. `.....where id in (your query to fetch IDs)`

Comment: Looks like you will have to dynamically build the LIKE part of your query in a string variable depending on whatever controls the number of likes you want

Comment: If you get the report ids using a MySQL query then you can do something like: `select * from table where field in (query that gets ids)`

Comment: @Kulvar Inner Join was the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> get the report IDs that the user can access (the variable number)

To prepare the id part of the query, you can do something like (pseudo code)

**EDIT:** I don't know if you are getting IDs from DB or network so this string solution is for both but you can replace the id list with something like "`(select id from another_table where some_field = some_criteria)`"

```
string idsString = "(";
index for ids do
  idsString += ids[index]
  if not last item
    idsString += ","
done
idsString += ")";
```

> and then get the details for each of these reports.

to complete your query run:

```
string queryStrnig = "select * from table where id in " + idsString;
```